# Group by datetime issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT
month(CA.PromiseDate) as [Miesiąc]
,year(CA.PromiseDate) as [Rok]
,x.[Deklaracje] as [Deklaracje]
,x.[Bpotw] as [Bpotw]
,x.[Potw] as [Potw]
,C.ClientId
,C.SetId
,K.NameShort
,U.FirstName
,U.LastName
from (
SELECT
CaseDetailId
,sum(case when CaseActionHistory.CaseActionDefinitionId = 34 then PromiseValue else 0 end) AS [Deklaracje]
,sum(case when CaseActionHistory.CaseActionDefinitionId = 35 then PromiseValue else 0 end) AS [Bpotw]
,sum(case when CaseActionHistory.CaseActionDefinitionId = 36 then PromiseValue else 0 end) AS [Potw]
from
CaseActionHistory
group by
CaseDetailId
) as x
join CaseActionHistory as CA on CA.CaseDetailId = x.CaseDetailId
join CaseDetails as C on CA.CaseDetailId = C.CaseDetailsId
join Client as K on C.ClientId = K.ClientId
join ClientProducts as CP on C.ProductId = CP.ClientProductId
join Users as U on CA.UserId = U.UserId
join CaseDetailsView as CDV on C.CaseId = CDV.CaseId
WHERE
(CA.IsDeleted IS NULL or CA.IsDeleted <> 'True')
and
(C.ClientId = @ClientId or @ClientId IS NULL)
and
(CA.CaseActionDefinitionId in (34,35,36,99))
and
(C.CaseStatusId not in (6,2))
and
(CA.PromiseDate >= CDV.EndServiceDate)
and
(U.UserId = @User or @User IS NULL)
and
(CA.PromiseDate >= @Min or @Min IS NULL)
and
(CA.PromiseDate <= @Max or @Max IS NULL)
and
CA.PromiseValue > 0

group by C.ClientId, C.SetId, K.NameShort, year(PromiseDate), month(PromiseDate) ,U.FirstName, U.LastName, x.Deklaracje, x.Bpotw, x.Potw
```

Works fine except grouping part. It groups whole PromiseDate not only by year and month as it should. It's showing results like this:

http://oi44.tinypic.com/141719i.jpg

However it should show all of those as 1 record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited due to comments below:

Try this (not tested)

```
SELECT
month(CA.PromiseDate) as [Miesiąc]
,year(CA.PromiseDate) as [Rok]
,sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 34 then PromiseValue else 0 end) AS [Deklaracje]
,sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 35 then PromiseValue else 0 end) AS [Bpotw]
,sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 36 then PromiseValue else 0 end) AS [Potw]
,C.ClientId
,C.SetId
,K.NameShort
,U.FirstName
,U.LastName
from  
CaseActionHistory as CA
join CaseDetails as C on CA.CaseDetailId = C.CaseDetailsId
join Client as K on C.ClientId = K.ClientId
join ClientProducts as CP on C.ProductId = CP.ClientProductId
join Users as U on CA.UserId = U.UserId
join CaseDetailsView as CDV on C.CaseId = CDV.CaseId
WHERE
(CA.IsDeleted IS NULL or CA.IsDeleted <> 'True')
and
(C.ClientId = @ClientId or @ClientId IS NULL)
and
(CA.CaseActionDefinitionId in (34,35,36,99))
and
(C.CaseStatusId not in (6,2))
and
(CA.PromiseDate >= CDV.EndServiceDate)
and
(U.UserId = @User or @User IS NULL)
and
(CA.PromiseDate >= @Min or @Min IS NULL)
and
(CA.PromiseDate <= @Max or @Max IS NULL)
and
CA.PromiseValue > 0
group by C.ClientId, C.SetId, K.NameShort, year(PromiseDate), month       (PromiseDate) ,U.FirstName,     U.LastName
```

Comment: Yup. However it's not possible not to group by this value, cause otherwise it would show error of "Deklaracje" not being used in aggregate function or group by statement.

Comment: My bad - I didn't see you table X - I'll have another look

Comment: Query itself works, I mean it shows results however those results aren't correct. Shows much more than it should.

Comment: Hmmm - difficult to work with just the SQL - if you post some tables and dummy data then I'm happy to help